# autoit modi.document error Variable must be of type "Object"

Tags: ocr, autoit, modi

```
#include <Constants.au3>
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>
#Include <Misc.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
#include <GDIPlus.au3>


$image = @MyDocumentsDir & "\aaa_teste.jpg"
ConsoleWrite(OCR($image))


Func OCR($Image)
    Local $miDoc, $Doc
    Local $str
    Local $oWord
    Local $sArray[500]
    Local $as_Text = ""


    $miDoc = ObjCreate("MODI.Document")
    ConsoleWrite("ObjCreate - The error value is: " & @error & @CRLF)
    $miDoc.Create(@TempDir & '\OCR_ImageResize.jpg')
    ConsoleWrite("Create - The error value is: " & @error & @CRLF)
    $miDoc.Ocr(9, False, False)
    ConsoleWrite("Ocr - The error value is: " & @error & @CRLF)

    If $Error = False Then
        $i = 0
        For $oWord in $miDoc.Images(0).Layout.Words

            $str = $str & $oWord.text & @CrLf
                ConsoleWrite($oWord.text & @CRLF)
            $sArray [$i] = $oWord.text
            $i += 1

        Next

        $as_Text = _ArrayToString($sArray," ",0)
        $as_Text = StringReplace($as_Text, "  ", "", 0)

    ElseIf $Error = True Then

        $Error = False
    EndIf

    $miDoc.Close(False)
    Return $as_Text

EndFunc
```

I`m trying read a text from a screencapture The error is:

"C:\Users\jose.barbosaneto\Desktop\TESTE.au3" (23) : ==> Variable must be of type "Object".:
$miDoc.Create(@TempDir & '\OCR_ImageResize.jpg')
$miDoc^ ERROR

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only downside of MODI library is that it relies 100 % on MS Office.
So if you don't have the proper version installed it will not find the needed COM object.

Check the Office version you have installed and see if MODI is in there.
Go in Uninstall Programs and click on Change/Repair on the MS Office version you have. From there you can check if MODI documents are installed.

Edit: Install MDI to TIFF Files Converter and SharePoint Designer from this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982760
After installing them go to > Uninstall a Program>MS Office SharePoint Designer 2007> Right click on it and select Change>select Add or Remove Features.
From there in the menu you will find the option Office Tools. Expand it.
Then click on the small arrows on MODI(Microsoft Office Document Imaging) and select "Run all from my Computer".

And you are ready to go!

Edit2: Here is a tested and working example.

```
#include <GUIConstants.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Dim $miDoc, $Doc
Dim $str
Dim $oWord
Dim $sArray[500]

Const $miLANG_CZECH = 5
Const $miLANG_DANISH = 6
Const $miLANG_DUTCH = 19
Const $miLANG_ENGLISH = 9
Const $miLANG_FINNISH = 11
Const $miLANG_FRENCH = 12
Const $miLANG_GERMAN = 7
Const $miLANG_GREEK = 8
Const $miLANG_HUNGARIAN = 14
Const $miLANG_ITALIAN = 16
Const $miLANG_JAPANESE = 17
Const $miLANG_KOREAN = 18
Const $miLANG_NORWEGIAN = 20
Const $miLANG_POLISH = 21
Const $miLANG_PORTUGUESE = 22
Const $miLANG_RUSSIAN = 25
Const $miLANG_SPANISH = 10
Const $miLANG_SWEDISH = 29
Const $miLANG_TURKISH = 31
Const $miLANG_SYSDEFAULT = 2048
Const $miLANG_CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED = 2052
Const $miLANG_CHINESE_TRADITIONAL = 1028

Local $ImagePath = @DesktopDir & "\Untitled.png" ; you can choose .tif format if you also want
; Initialize error handler
$oMyError = ObjEvent("AutoIt.Error", "MyErrFunc")

$miDoc = ObjCreate("MODI.Document")
$miDocView = ObjCreate("MiDocViewer.MiDocView")

$Viewer = GUICreate("Embedded MODI Viewer", 640, 580, (@DesktopWidth - 640) / 2, (@DesktopHeight - 580) / 2, _
        $WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW + $WS_VISIBLE + $WS_CLIPSIBLINGS)


;Creates an ActiveX Control in the GUI.
$GUIActiveX = GUICtrlCreateObj($miDocView, -1, -1, 640, 580)
GUICtrlSetResizing($Viewer, $GUI_DOCKAUTO)


$miDoc.Create($ImagePath)
$miDoc.Ocr($miLANG_ENGLISH, True, False)

; Show GUI
GUISetState()

$miDocView.Document = $miDoc
$miDocView.SetScale(0.75, 0.75)


While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()

    If $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE Then ExitLoop
WEnd



$i = 0

For $oWord In $miDoc.Images(0).Layout.Words

    $str = $str & $oWord.text & @CRLF
    ConsoleWrite($oWord.text & @CRLF)
    $sArray[$i] = $oWord.text
    $i += 1
Next

_ArrayDisplay($sArray, "OCR Result")



;MsgBox(0,"",$miDocView.FileName)

;------------------------------ This is a COM Error handler --------------------------------
Func MyErrFunc()
    $HexNumber = Hex($oMyError.number, 8)
    MsgBox(0, "COM Error Test", "We intercepted a COM Error !" & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
            "err.description is: " & @TAB & $oMyError.description & @CRLF & _
            "err.windescription:" & @TAB & $oMyError.windescription & @CRLF & _
            "err.number is: " & @TAB & $HexNumber & @CRLF & _
            "err.lastdllerror is: " & @TAB & $oMyError.lastdllerror & @CRLF & _
            "err.scriptline is: " & @TAB & $oMyError.scriptline & @CRLF & _
            "err.source is: " & @TAB & $oMyError.source & @CRLF & _
            "err.helpfile is: " & @TAB & $oMyError.helpfile & @CRLF & _
            "err.helpcontext is: " & @TAB & $oMyError.helpcontext _
            )
    SetError(1) ; to check for after this function returns
EndFunc   ;==>MyErrFunc
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i solved my problem. I had a office 2013 than i did a downgrade to office 2007